# PHP errors from ApiApplication

Tags: php, error-handling

I get PHP errors as unhandled exceptions but I don't really see any information that can help me.  How can I troubleshoot this?

```
Unhandled exception - Joomla\CMS\Application\Exception\NotAcceptable

A PHP Exception occurred on your site. Here you can find the stack trace:
Exception Type: Joomla\CMS\Application\Exception\NotAcceptable
File: /home/*****/public_html/libraries/src/Application/ApiApplication.php
Line: 264
Message: Could not match accept header 
#0 /home/*****/public_html/libraries/src/Application/ApiApplication.php(107): Joomla\CMS\Application\ApiApplication->route()
#1 /home/*****/public_html/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(294): Joomla\CMS\Application\ApiApplication->doExecute()
#2 /home/*****/public_html/api/includes/app.php(53): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#3 /home/*****/public_html/api/index.php(31): require_once('/home/*****...')
#4 {main}
Request information
GET variables
Array
(
)
POST variables
Array
(
)
COOKIE variables
Array
(
)
REQUEST variables
Array
(
)
SERVER variables
Array
(
    [PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive
    [HTTP_HOST] => www.*****.co.uk
    [HTTP_X_HTTPS] => 1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/*****/public_html
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => *****
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 12961
    [SERVER_ADDR] => *****
    [SERVER_NAME] => www.*****.co.uk
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@*****.co.uk
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
    [REQUEST_URI] => /api/Probe
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /api/Probe
    [REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [HTTPS] => on
    [HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] => 
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [SSL_PROTOCOL] => TLSv1.2
    [SSL_CIPHER] => ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    [SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE] => 256
    [SSL_CIPHER_ALGKEYSIZE] => 256
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/*****/public_html/api/index.php
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [SCRIPT_URI] => https://www.*****.co.uk/api/Probe
    [SCRIPT_URL] => /api/Probe
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /api/index.php
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => LiteSpeed
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [X-LSCACHE] => on,crawler
    [PHP_SELF] => /api/index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1666174375.9687
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1666174375
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're using to make the request doesn't send the `Accept` header. API application by default expects a request that accepts `application/vnd.api+json` response. Specific routes may use different values. If you want to accept any type, use the catch-all `*/*` value.

Comment: Ok but how do I know what didn't send the header?

Comment: What are you using to make the request?

Comment: I'm not, I'm getting an email saying there was a PHP error and it gives me that information.  Admin Tools sends it.  But it would either be a user or a bot that triggered something to cause the error.